# How to create local database Instance using SMO

Tags: c#, database, instance, smo, localdb

I have installed localdatabase and created a shared instance, and using smo I am able to create localdatabase.

For my requirement I have to create a localdb shared instance.

I am creating local database using SMO like this.

```
ServerConnection serConn = new ServerConnection(@"(localdb)\.\sharedIns");
Server ldbServer = new Server(serConn);

Database db = new Database(ldbServer , "databaseName");
db.Create();
```

Before creating database, I am creating shared instance through command prompt using sqllocaldb.exe like this

```
c:\>sqllocaldb create testIns
c:\>sqllocaldb share testIn sharedIns
```

I want to remove these manual steps and create localdb shared instance using SMO. How to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to create a sqllocaldb instance in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637663/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-sqllocaldb-instance-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

I maintain an open-source .NET library that wraps the underlying LocalDB native API, exposing an interface that allows you do this this kind of thing. See the below links for more detail:

- [SQL LocalDB Wrapper on GitHub](https://github.com/martincostello/sqllocaldb)
- [SQL LocalDB Wrapper on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MartinCostello.SqlLocalDb/)