# Is there a way to create a sqllocaldb instance in c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is there a way in c# to directly create a SQLLOCALDB instance?  At the moment, we use sqllocaldb.exe, but need to be able to do it without using the external executable.

Comment: Why can't you use the command line tool?  Could you call the executable from C# using `Process.Start`?

Comment: Have a look at SMO (Sql Server Management Objects).
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13755/SMO-Manage-your-SQL-Server

Comment: Calling out to an external executable is viewed as a security risk so Process.Start to the .EXE won't work for us.

Comment: There was another entry here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407474/how-to-create-local-database-instance-using-smo that went unanswered where someone was asking about using SMO to create a database instance.  The codeproject article seems to be able to address everything after the instance is created.

Answer (score 14):

You could use the [SQL LocalDB Wrapper](https://github.com/martincostello/sqllocaldb) library.

It wraps the native APIs exposed by SQL LocalDB in a .NET 4.0 assembly.

It is also now available via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MartinCostello.SqlLocalDb/).

Disclaimer: I maintain this library.

Answer (score 1):

If you want full control over your LocalDB configuration and don't mind having an additional dependency in your project, just use [Martin Costello's NuGet library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19381496/87698).

If you just want to ensure that a specific LocalDB instance exists *and* you know the exact version (and, thus, installation path) of your LocalDB instance, it might be easier to just P/Invoke [LocalDBCreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/express-localdb-instance-apis/localdbcreateinstance-function?view=sql-server-ver16). Here's an example using SQL Server 2019 LocalDB:

```
[DllImport("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\150\\LocalDB\\Binn\\SqlUserInstance.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int LocalDBCreateInstance(string wszVersion, string pInstanceName, int dwFlags);

...

// LocalDBCreateInstance also returns success (0) if the instance already
// exists, so there's no need to check.
var result = LocalDBCreateInstance("15.0", myInstanceName, 0);

if (result != 0)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException(
        $"LocalDBCreateInstance returned error code {result:X}.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I followed this approach. However, I got a PInvokeStackImbalance warning when running this under the debugger. I added CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl to the DllImport to fix that.

Comment: @WimCoenen: You're right. I just double-checked with msoledbsql.h and, indeed, it's a cdecl function. Thanks, I've fixed this (in my SO answer and in my own code). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I spotted a couple of projects that wrapper the native localdb API. I have not personally tried either of these but the following may be of use to you.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/LocalDbApi/
http://sqllocaldb.codeplex.com/